# Xcode 5, why isn't the image resizing?

Tags: uiimageview, xcode5, cgrectmake

Hello I am trying to resize a UIImage, but even though I'm not getting any errors it is not working.

hers the code of .h file

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *Fish;
```

heres the code of .m file

```
Fish.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 293);
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help

Comment: What's "`Fish`"?  A UIImageView or?  Is it an IBOutlet?

Comment: (See the edit for .h code)

Comment: So I guess the answer to your question is both...

Comment: and in what method is "`Fish.frame`" being called?  B.T.W., best practice in Objective-C is to begin variables with *lower case letters* (e.g. "`fish`" and not "`Fish`").

Comment: The viewController's viewDidLoad. I'm trying to resize based on the screen size so when the view loads I get the screen size and am trying to make the image's size proportional to that no matter what device.

Comment: Sorry the cap was just an old habit

Comment: I know how to get the height and width of he screen, the only part I'm having trouble with is then resizing my image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is probably not resizing because you are just resizing the image view. Make sure in your storyboard that you make the image view (Fish), have the move ScaleToFill. I can't do screenshot due to reputation ( sorry :( )

Alternately, if your goal is not to resize the image view but to resize the image it is holding, you can do this:

```
UIImage *image = Fish.image;
UIImage *image = YourImageView.image;
    UIImage *tempImage = nil;
    CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(80,60);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    thumbnailRect.origin = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = targetSize.width;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = targetSize.height;

    [image drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    tempImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    YourImageView.image = tempImage;
```

and you would set thumbnailRect to whatever size you want.

Hope this helps! Please search Nerdy Lime on the app store to find all of my apps! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I bet your outlet is not hooked up.  In your "`viewDidLoad`" method, try doing this:

```
if(Fish)
{
    Fish.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 293);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Fish is null; why did I forget to connect the outlet in my storyboard or xib?");
}
```

And this isn't the best way to resize your UIImageView.  If you're using regular springs & struts, you can grow an outlet by clicking the springs & struts to grow based on the superview's size, e.g.:

[image: Grow Everything]

And if you're doing AutoLayout, there's a different thing you can do (basically pin your view to all four sides of the superview).

Here is how I do it:

1) select the outlet / object you want to add constraints to (in your case, it'll be the fish image view)

2) see the segmented control at the bottom of the Interface Builder window?  Click on the second one and you'll see a popover view open up with a list of possible constraints to add.

3) In my example, I'm adding constraints in my ImageView to always be 10 pixels from each edge of the superview (note the four "10"s and ***solid*** red lines meaning I'm adding four constraints).

AutoLayout is a pain to get accustomed to (and I'm still learning it myself), but I suspect that once one gets the hang of it, it'll be a powerful new tool especially as Apple brings in additional iOS screen sizes in the very near future.

[image: Add New Constraints]

Comment: Haha no it's hooked up. In other parts of my file I've moved it around.

Comment: Are you saying there's a way to make the size change according to the views size without coding?

Comment: Yes, that's what the second part of my answer is saying.

Comment: Autosizing does not show up, does it matter that this is an iOS app?

Comment: sounds like you are using AutoLayout; hold on a few minutes, I will type up how to get your image view to resize...

Comment: ok thanks, the top half of you picture looks like my interface, but everything after the first section with the x,y,width,height isn't showing up

Comment: Okay… I've added additional instructions to my answer.  I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Ok yes this good, but can it work in percents? Like 10% from left?

Comment: Not via Interface Builder, but possibly via programatic constraints (which I don't have the experience or patience in to tell you how to do).

Comment: If its not possible to do percents then how can i change the size through coding? Because I know I can do percents that way, I just don't know why my resizing isn't working

Comment: maybe somebody else can take a stab at answering your question…

Comment: Ok well do you have the patients to c/p a link that shows me how?